# How to implement inet_pton() in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, byte

I am doing an IP header parsing and changing source IP address... before I was doing some how using `NIPQUAD` macro but not working properly then I found `inet_pton()` which changes string IP address to network byte order. I didn't understood :

- **how uint_32 (unsigned int) is being used to hold IP address?**
- **how this fuction is converting from string IP to network byte order?**
- **how it is being used to show IP address?**

`NIPQUAD` macro:

```
// use printf("%d.%d.%d.%d",NIPQUAD(iphdr->saddr));
#define NIPQUAD(addr) \
    ((unsigned char *)&addr)[0], \
    ((unsigned char *)&addr)[1], \
    ((unsigned char *)&addr)[2], \
    ((unsigned char *)&addr)[3]
```

Comment: IPv4 is 32-bits long. 1 byte represents 1 part of IP address. So for 4 parts, 4 bytes.

Comment: Changing the byte order means reversing the bytes. Swap bytes 1 with 4, 2 with 3.

Comment: ahh.. not getting can you please elaborate?

Comment: Maybe you should first try implement it yourself before asking this question? And do not use macro for that! This is quite simple, you should not have problem with that.

Comment: yeah, definitely I would love that but I didn't understood its proper functionality..

Comment: E.g. IP address 192.168.20.42 can be represented as a single integer of 32-bits (in hexadecimal) 0xc0a8142a. In hex, c0 is 192, a8 is 168, 14 is 20 and 2a is 42.

Comment: Thanks.. @kiner_shah , got it my first question...but need to clear rest..

Comment: For the above example, reversing the byte order will lead to: 0x2a14a8c0.

Comment: @kiner_shah oookey... got it!

Comment: @MarekR I am not doing that.. I just want to clear my doubt..

Comment: it was just a part of program that I didn't understood.. so  I asked to clear it respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how uint_32 (unsigned int) is being used to hold IP address?

An IP address is simply 4 numbers between 0 and 255, so 4 bytes. It fits into a `uint32_t` quite nicely:

```
1.2.3.4       -> 0x01020304
127.0.0.1     -> 0x7F000001
192.168.10.20 -> 0xC0A80A14
```

In C, if your machine is *big endian*, this would be something like:

```
uint32_t addr;
uint8_t *tmp = (uint8_t *)&addr;

tmp[0] = 192;
tmp[1] = 168;
tmp[2] = 10;
tmp[3] = 20;
```

While if it is *little endian* you need to assign the 4 bytes of the IP in reverse order to have the same value. [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) can be checked either using compiler directives or doing a runtime check (the first option is almost always the one that is used).

> how this fuction is converting from string IP to network byte order?

`inet_pton` just converts each number in the string to a byte, and then composes the final value like I showed above. This can be done by splitting the string on the various dots (`.`) using `strtok` or similar functions. Since network order means *big endian*, your final result will always be big endian, so no need to swap things around.

---

There are several implementations of `inet_pton()` on the web, here are two:

- [Musl libc](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/network/inet_pton.c#n15)
- [Glibc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/595c22ecd8e87a27fd19270ed30fdbae9ad25426/resolv/inet_pton.c#L80-L122) - a bit more convoluted.

Turns out that both of those implementations do not use `strtok()`, `atoi()`, `strtol()` or any similar function, instead they simply parse the string by hand one character at a time. The conversion is done character by character.

Comment: I thinks the algorithm for inet_pton() should be like:  first it extract string numbers from IP string with strtok and then it convert the number with atoi and then reverse its byte order like 1.2.3.4 -> 0x04030201..please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @GeekyJarvis yes that makes sense in general, however to be precise note that (1) it cannot use `strtok()` directly on the provided string because `strtok()` would modify the string (which is `const char *`), so it is more likely using `strchr()` to locate the dots, or it copies it in a temporary buffer and then uses `strtok()`; (2) it cannot use `atoi()` because that function does not detect errors, it almost certainly uses `strtol()`.

Comment: @MarcoBoneli ahh.. didn't got it, sorry... If possible can you share its implementation too in your  above answer.. it would be honour.

Comment: @MarcoBoneli I tried but didn't work as expected.

Comment: @GeekyJarvis you can very easily look at how `inet_pton` is implemented in GLIBC or Musl LIBC since they are open source. I have added two links in my answer, check them out. If you have a problem regarding your particular implementation I would suggest you to ask a separate question where you show the code and explain what is not working.

Comment: @MarcoBoneli sure.. and again thanks a lot for you help, I really appreciate it..

Answer (score -1):

I think you got the other answer, here is the implementation part:

> how this fuction is converting from string IP to network byte order? I would appreciate if anyone provide code.

```
int inet_pton(int af, const char *restrict s, void *restrict a0)
{
    uint16_t ip[8];
    unsigned char *a = a0;
    int i, j, v, d, brk=-1, need_v4=0;

    if (af==AF_INET) {
        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            for (v=j=0; j<3 && isdigit(s[j]); j++)
                v = 10*v + s[j]-'0';
            if (j==0 || (j>1 && s[0]=='0') || v>255) return 0;
            a[i] = v;
            if (s[j]==0 && i==3) return 1;
            if (s[j]!='.') return 0;
            s += j+1;
        }
        return 0;
    } else if (af!=AF_INET6) {
        errno = EAFNOSUPPORT;
        return -1;
    }

    if (*s==':' && *++s!=':') return 0;

    for (i=0; ; i++) {
        if (s[0]==':' && brk<0) {
            brk=i;
            ip[i&7]=0;
            if (!*++s) break;
            if (i==7) return 0;
            continue;
        }
        for (v=j=0; j<4 && (d=hexval(s[j]))>=0; j++)
            v=16*v+d;
        if (j==0) return 0;
        ip[i&7] = v;
        if (!s[j] && (brk>=0 || i==7)) break;
        if (i==7) return 0;
        if (s[j]!=':') {
            if (s[j]!='.' || (i<6 && brk<0)) return 0;
            need_v4=1;
            i++;
            break;
        }
        s += j+1;
    }
    if (brk>=0) {
        memmove(ip+brk+7-i, ip+brk, 2*(i+1-brk));
        for (j=0; j<7-i; j++) ip[brk+j] = 0;
    }
    for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
        *a++ = ip[j]>>8;
        *a++ = ip[j];
    }
    if (need_v4 && inet_pton(AF_INET, (void *)s, a-4) <= 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Other than blindly copy-pasting some code from Mustl libc ([here](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/network/inet_pton.c?h=v1.2.2&id=85e0e3519655220688e757b9d5bfd314923548bd)) without any useful explanation, you could at least link or mention it.